# Unable to run .Net Core self contained Application in mac (Permission Denied)

Tags: c#, .net-core, macos-sierra

I need to run a self contained .net core application in mac. I been able to do this in Linux and in Windows. I am only missing to run this application in mac. Maybe I am doing something wrong. This is what I am doing:

1) Create a hello world application target .Net Core 2.1

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp4
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        }
    }
}
```

2) Publish that application for Mac `osx.10.12-x64`. On command prompt I run the following command:

```
dotnet publish "C:\Users\Foooooo\ConsoleApp4.csproj" --self-contained --runtime osx.10.12-x64
```

3) I then place that output in the mac and switch to root user in terminal with:

```
sudo -i
```

4) I then try to execute my application as `./ConsoleApp4` **But I get an error message saying permission denied**.

[image]

---

### P.S.

I know I can install dotnet core on the mac and then run my executable as `dotnet ./ConsoleApp4`. **I do not want to install dotnet core on the mac I want to take advantage of the `--self-contained` feature**. This works great when publishing into windows (`--runtime win7-x64`) and linux (`--runtime linux-x64`). I am just missing to run this app on mac. **Why do I get the permission denied error if I am root on the terminal?**

---

### Solution

Sorry I am not a mac/linux guy I forgot to execute `chmod +x` on the file. When I googled for permissions if found the command `sudo -i`. Thanks @chue for the solution on your comments.

Comment: It seems strange that your binary ends in "dll" and not "exe". Perhaps there's something in the csproj that we don't know about?

Comment: When you publish for windows `--runtime win7-x64` you get a .exe file. But when you publish for mac or linux the output file does not contain an exe. I know this because I already tried it on linux and it worked when I ran the command `./ConsoleApp4` on ubuntu.

Comment: Just taking a guess, but does the application have execute permisions? `chmod 777 ConsoleApp4`

Comment: Or `chmod u+x ConsoleApp4`